# SEARCH API: Adding Documents To An Index

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

I have been using Search API for my application so far successfully. I was able to add documents to index successfully yesterday.

But when I tried to execute the same today, it gave me this exception.

**Exception:**

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.appengine.api.search.Index.add(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/google/appengine/api/search/AddDocumentsResponse;

I am trying to add only one document to an index and that its not working.
Please give me the solution to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be correlated with the appearance of [app-engine 1.6.6 pre-release](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/8zmSKSYJC_o) in which **AddDocumentResponse** is deprecated.

Maybe after you deploy a version with this pre-release, the insert of new documents will work fine.

(*) For me, it's working fine with the old code from 1.6.5 sdk.